# Rose leaves died

Tags: leaves, roses

I have rose plant in a pot. It was blooming earlier,then all the leaves got fall. I believe it's due to fall season. But now the new leaves are there, they are also bending towards down. Looks like about to die.
Can someone suggest what to do.[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a rose bush?

Comment: Yes, it is rose bush, there were flowers in earlier or the season.